# Two level Bucketing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, buckets

I am a newbie in pandas,
I reviewed some of the listed solution to bucket dataframe but none of them seems to be my answer.
i have a time series data which I am not going to use resampling for them, the way I want to bucket is divide whole data into 7 groups and each group into 10 equal buckets. I am sure there must be very straight way rather than using index here.

## More details

### Dataframe

```
tick: 2014-11-03 00:00:07,...
date_part: 4972807141,  4972807143
spot: 0.8752, 0.8753,... 
length:1405
```

the ticks i want to be grouped into 7 and each point to exact 10 spot bucket and then other column can use aggregation function up to spot bucket level, which will be total 7X10 records.

Comment: Can you try to explain your problem a little bit more?  Maybe show us what you've tried to do?  Or maybe show us your input and your expceted output?  See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I have added more details about my problem.

Comment: I'm still unclear about how the input should match up the the output.  Can you post a sample of your actual input that can be copy-pasted into our own terminals?  And then post a code sample of how the output should look?